# How can I remove the encoding line in SPSS syntax editor?

Tags: spss

Every time I work on SPSS syntax file and save it, this line automatically pops out on the top: *** Encoding: windows-1252.**

How can I disable this line, or make it not happen at the first place?

The reason I ask is because my syntax will source from another syntax file. The problem seems to be that can't be done with this encoding line.

EDIT: Actually it looks like any type of encoding will "stick" on my syntax file. For example, if I specify: **set unicode yes.** then this will appear on the top line: *** Encoding: UTF-8.** Again, it doesn't go away. Say, I delete it but, upon clicking on save, it comes back.

Answer (score 1):

This line is just an informative comment about the encoding of the file.  Would you explain in more detail why this causes a problem?

Comment: My guess is that it's because of the SPSS version. I can modify the appearance of the `Encoding` line on SPSS 20 on Data tab, but such option isn't available on SPSS 23, which I'm using.

Comment: That line is written by the syntax editor to reflect the encoding of that particular syntax fie.  It has nothing to do with the data.  And you can choose the encoding to save the syntax in from the Save As drop down in the SE.  But I can't think of a scenario where this line would cause a problem.